# How to convert a GeoPosition to a GeoCoordinate? WIndows Phone

Tags: c#, casting, geocoding

I have passed a GeoPosition variable to a class and I need to convert it to type GeoCoordinate,but when I use the latitude and longtitude variables of type `var` it gives me an error that GeoCoordinate takes `(double,double)` parameters.

I understand that this means it has to take double parameters but how do I convert or cast the latitude and longtitude variables to be passed to its GeoCoordinate's constructor? Should I be converting using a different method?

```
if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("GeoLat") && NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("GeoLong"))
            {
              var latitude = NavigationContext.QueryString["GeoLat"];
              var longtitude = NavigationContext.QueryString["GeoLong"];
              var MyGeoPosition = new GeoCoordinate(latitude , longtitude ); 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MSDN documentation, it looks like [NavigationContext.QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationcontext.querystring%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is an `IDictionary<string, string>`.  This means that your two variables will be of type `string`.

Try casting your latitude and longitude variables to a type of `double`.

```
var latitude = Convert.ToDouble(NavigationContext.QueryString["GeoLat"]);
var longtitude = Convert.ToDouble(NavigationContext.QueryString["GeoLong"]);
```